# Why is this MinDepth level solution so slow compared to recursive solution?

Tags: java, binary-tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

The problem is find minimum depth of a binary tree, such that running on the following tree:

```
    *           :Level 1
   / \
  *   *         :Level 2
     / \
    *  NULL     :Level 3
```

would return the mindepth to be 2.

I was able to get a recursive solution that beats 100% of other solutions according to leetcode, which did not make sense to me as how can it be so fast if it has to visit every child of every node (implementation of DFS).

I instead decided to do it in a BFS manner rather than DFS, and check whether there is a node in each level that has no children, and that would be min-depth.

Here is my recursive solution:

```
public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    else if (root.left == null) 
        return minDepth(root.right) + 1;
    else if (root.right == null) 
        return minDepth(root.left) + 1;
    else 
        return Math.min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right)) + 1;
}
```

Here is my level solution:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        ArrayList<TreeNode> q = new ArrayList<TreeNode>(); // We will store each new node here
        q.add(root); // add the root to our queue
        return root != null ? minDepthHelper(q, 0) : 0; // If the root node is null, dont bother and return 0

    }

    private int minDepthHelper(ArrayList<TreeNode> q, int depth){
        if(q.size() == 0) // Empty queue means nothing to do, so return
            return depth;

        int size = q.size(); // How many we will need to pop (the parents)
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            TreeNode curr = q.get(0); // FIFO!
            if(curr.left == null && curr.right == null){
                return depth +1; // If you have no children, then you are a leaf so return your depth. 
                                            // nodes 0 through size are on the same level, so any of them , if they have 
                                            // no children, will return the same value which will be min depth.
            }else{
                // Add only non-null children!
                if(curr.left != null)
                    q.add(curr.left);
                if(curr.right != null)
                    q.add(curr.right);
            }
            q.remove(0);
        }
        // Will only reach here if no nodes in level depth have no right and no left
        return minDepthHelper(q, depth+1);
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain why the second solution is slower, even though it should make less comparisons?

Comment: q.remove(0) is slow.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I thought it was O(1) as java handles arraylists like linked lists, and removing the front element is 1 pointer away.

Comment: Nope, removing the front of an ArrayList means shifting all the other elements up.  You can use an ArrayDeque if you want to be able to remove the front quickly.

Comment: @MattTimmermans that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't put a whole lot of weight on the LeetCode percentages. When I submit your recursive solution, it shows it beats 34%. LeetCode also shows the exact same example code for both 100% and 34% segments. One can only guess what exactly their test cases are. All implementations I submitted run in 1 ms, so chances are, all 41 of their test cases are very small trees such that performance differences are totally negligible. You also don't know what kind of tree structures dominate the example cases--they could all be more or less worst-case time complexity, in which case BFS has little or no advantage over DFS.

With that in mind, let's benchmark your code on large test cases to see if we can gain some understanding that can't be obtained on the black-box testing environment that LeetCode offers.

Before we do, let's examine your BFS solution, which uses recursion and manipulates an ArrayList as if it were a queue. It's true that ArrayList shift operations are amortized O(1), but using an ArrayDeque is a much faster and more semantically appropriate data structure for queueing operations in Java.

Additionally, by using recursion in your BFS implementation, you're negating one of the primary benefits of BFS, which is that it's iterative. Not having to manipulate the call stack should cut a good deal of overhead.

Putting that all together, I'd write the BFS function like:

```
public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    ArrayDeque<Pair<TreeNode, Integer>> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
    q.offer(new Pair(root, 1));

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Pair<TreeNode, Integer> curr = q.poll();

        if (curr.first != null) {
            if (curr.first.left == null && curr.first.right == null) {
                return curr.second;
            }

            q.offer(new Pair(curr.first.left, curr.second + 1));
            q.offer(new Pair(curr.first.right, curr.second + 1));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, a quick benchmark. Here, `BFS2` is your BFS implementation and `BFS` is mine:

```
long BFSTotal = 0;
long BFS2Total = 0;
long DFSTotal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    TreeNode root = randomTree(10000);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    minDepthDFS(root);
    DFSTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    minDepthBFS(root);
    BFSTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    minDepthBFS2(root);
    BFS2Total += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
}

System.out.println("BFS: " + BFSTotal);
System.out.println("BFS2: " + BFS2Total);
System.out.println("DFS: " + DFSTotal);
```

This code creates 10000 different trees, each with 10000 nodes created using a coin toss algorithm, and runs the algorithms on each tree. Here are the results from a few runs:

```
BFS: 1906
BFS2: 5484
DFS: 3351

BFS: 1709
BFS2: 6101
DFS: 3773

BFS: 1527
BFS2: 5567
DFS: 3856
```

Go ahead and [run the code yourself](https://repl.it/repls/VastDecisivePolygon) and experiment a bit. I don't think these results are absolutely conclusive, but they do reinforce my basic premises: BFS beats DFS because of less overhead and potential to bail early (worst case time complexities are the same), and a non-recursive BFS implementation using an efficient data structure beats a recursive BFS implementation that uses an inefficient data structure.

This also demonstrates that your BFS implementation is roughly twice as slow as your DFS implementation, which *may* explain your LeetCode results, but again, I'd hesitate to jump to any conclusions given how tiny their test cases seem to be.

Comment: WOW! What an excellent answer! Thank you so much! So I guess I had the right idea, but my execution was not the best? Mainly being recursive rather than iterative and also using an ArrayList rather than an ArrayDequeue (I honestly never heard of this, will check it out). 

Any idea why using the ArrayDequeue would be faster? Like you said, the operations on the linked list that I am using are O(1), so how would a different structure do it faster?

Comment: And I noticed that your BFS implementation is MUCH faster than mine. Is this because of you not using an arraylist and doing it iteratively?

Comment: Yep, you had the right idea. ArrayList and ArrayDeque are both array-based. ArrayList is a resizable abstraction on primitive arrays, the idea being O(1) random access to elements. The downside is slower add/removals. It's still O(1), but slower O(1) than a deque because in a deque, a `poll` or `offer` just shifts the head/tail pointers around, with some occasional resizing, and doesn't need to reposition anything. You can modify my test code to see whether the ArrayList or the recursion imposes a larger penalty. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-deque for more on the ArrayDeque.